# How to review the codes from .ipynb files in Mac OS ?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have some code to review and the files have extensions of `.ipynb` in the end. I install `IPython` using the command `sudo pip install ipython`. Now, when I type `ipython` in the terminal, I get the return `-bash: ipyhton: command not found`.

What I could do now to review those files? Python is installed in the system. I read the I need to use the command `ipython notebook file_name.ipynb` to run those files from the terminal.

Comment: The notebook part of IPython got renamed to Jupyter; `pip install jupyter` and then run `jupyter notebook`.

Comment: I tried but getting the same kind of error  `-bash: jupyter: command not found`

Comment: Can you find a file named `jupyter` (no file extension) anywhere on your computer? The relevant directory may not be on $PATH.

Comment: I had to uninstall and to re-install and now this works fine.